# How to prevent redirecting to page which is loaded in jquery ui tabs

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using JQuery ui tabs in my application. When I click on a button control on "Login.asxp"  it redirects to 'Login.aspx' page (which is content page) and tabs disappear.

JQTabs.aspx

```
<div id="tabs" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab Three</a></li>
        </ul>
```

[image]

Here is Jquery code.

```
  $("#tabs").tabs({
                avtive: $("#tabs-1").load('Tab1.aspx'),
                beforeActivate: function (e, ui) {
                    var tabName = ui.newTab.text();                    
                    if (tabName == "Tab One") {
                        $("#tabs-1").load('Tab1.aspx');
                    }
                    if (tabName == "Tab Two") {
                        $("#tabs-2").load('Tab2.aspx');
                    }
                    if (tabName == "Tab Three") {
                        $("#tabs-3").load('Tab3.aspx');
                    }
                }
            });
```

How can I prevent redirecting to 'Login.aspx' page on postback?